# Trouble installing 'Matrix' package using packrat on browser based rStudio

Tags: r, install.packages, packrat

I have troubles with importing project from a local machine to a server-based rStudio environment, when i use the specified repository and guidelines i get this error when i try to restore my local packrat library:

```
Installing Matrix (1.2-10) ... 
[1] "Command failed (1)\n\nFailed to run system        command:\n\n\t'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix' --library='/home/robinzacha/51_SocialCharging-master-4f660542fd180508e8e7fbbd0f88d6569ec89acc/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.3' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo \n\nThe command failed with output:\n* installing *source* package 'Matrix' ...\n** package 'Matrix' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked\n** libs\nmake[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD'\n( cd Lib ; make clean )\nmake[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD/Lib'\nmake[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD/Lib'\nmake[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD'\nmake[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD'\n( cd Source ; make clean )\nmake[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD/Source'\nmake[2]:    Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD/Source'\nmak...    <truncated>
```

Error: Command failed (1)

```
Failed to run system command:

'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix' --library='/home/robinzacha/51_SocialCharging-master-4f660542fd180508e8e7fbbd0f88d6569ec89acc/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.3' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo
```

The command failed with output:
* installing *source* package 'Matrix' ...
** package 'Matrix' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD'
( cd Lib ; make clean )
make[2]: Entering directory`/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD/Lib'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD/Lib'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/CHOLMOD'
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD'
( cd Source ; make clean )
make[2]: Entering directory`/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD/Source'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/RtmpKwkp2a/Matrix/src/COLAMD/Source'
make[1]: Leaving dir

Do anyone have an idea to fix this problem? I've searched the web for similar problems and haven't had any luck finding anything useful to my understanding.

Thanks in advance!